Parameter sweep: Apparent exponential decay of improvement of processing time with added CPUs?
I recently ran a simple parameter sweep of a Python script I have written which includes mltiprocessing. I sequentially assessed N files (adding 20 files per iteration) across 4, 8, 12, and 16 CPUs and assessed how long the process took to run. I ran this on a node exclusive to my job (i.e. no other processes were competing for resources)
Results:

As you can see, the processing time improved with increasing CPUs. However, I did notice that the change in the improvement appeared to be following an exponential decay trend. I had a quick peek at the processing time per plate, and the exponential decay trend was more obvious:

The relevant part of the code is here:
list_of_sub_dfs = [group.reset_index(drop=True) for _, group in df.groupby('Unique_identifier')]

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=int(args.processors)) as pool:
    partial_process_wrapper = partial(process_well, smoothing_factor=smoothing_fact,normalize=normalize_data)
    results = pool.map(partial_process_wrapper, list_of_sub_dfs)
    for original_curve_rows, sub_curve_rows, Tm_rows in results:
        all_original_curve_rows.extend(original_curve_rows)
        all_subcurves.extend(sub_curve_rows)
        all_tm_rows.extend(Tm_rows)

In short: The input data is broken into equal sized chunks (split by a unique identifier in the data) and fed into the process_well function which spits out several lists.
Could anyone explain why this trend is occurring? Is there anything I can do to make the difference in performance more linear with the number of CPUs used?
Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide :)

You have a bottleneck somewhere. It could be lots of things like storage speed, OS call speed, data transfer back to main process, etc.. look into profiling for multiprocessing.

Also be aware that inter-process communication can be rather slow, especially when a sequential process submit tasks to many workers. The later ones may starve. The main solution is to perform heavy-grained tasks and reduce as much as possible the amount of data transferred between processes (i.e. avoid sending a full dataframe while only a fraction is needed). Multiprocessing tends not to scale on many-core systems (more generally CPython parallelism really sucks).


Q2 :" Is there anything I can do to make the difference in performance more linear with the number of CPUs used? "

Yes,
design the code ( The Process) so as to have minimal, best zero, SERIAL part of the End-to-End process-flow and do not add any add-on overhead costs. Then and only then your processing will follow the Amdahl's Law ( and only the atomicity-of-work will be your principal glass ceiling for performance boosting ) given all other resources do not block your process-flow ( which they do in real hardware -- number of mem-I/O channels being the first such performance blocker, though maskable to some extent by the NUMA-cache hierarchy. Yet the principle of scare resources block any further performance boosting is clear in this ).

Q1 :" Could anyone explain why this trend is occurring? "

Well, the speedup scaling was first explained by Dr. Gene AMDAHL in early days of mainframe computing in the last Millenium. His initial formulation became known as the "Law of diminishing returns", saying in principle, that no matter how many resources you add to the process-flow, even if adding infinitely many such resources, the speedup boost of each new added resource is less and less, as finally adding zero new speedup ( as the effect of the ceiling of diminishing returns was met, where the processing time remains still bound to still at least the time of the SERIAL part of the flow of processing, adding more resources to PARALLEL part will not cut the still-SERIAL part shorter a single femtosecond ...
That simple - exact formulae are here and interactive tools to simulate / animate the effects of parameters are available, as often cited here

Awesome, thank you for the thorough answer. Just to confirm I've understood - the underlying bottleneck(s) that is minimizing the performance improvement is any part of the code that needs to run sequentially and cannot be parallelized? And the solution is (if possible) to find ways to parallelize any tasks/processes that I can?

Absolutely. SERIAL sections run best if not present at all, or using Ferrari w rocket-boosters ... as fast engine as possible, as short racing track as possible ( design as best as possible as this has to be done anyways, before any smart things might start - organisation matters, data-flow matters, delays add-up serially too, no latency masking tricks help here, as all is SEQUENTIAL, so latencies are too ). PARALLEL sections perform best if no (b)locking or shared resources inject a need of "coordination" between parallel flows, having 6 Ferraris AND 6 lane HWY, is hell faster then on 2 lanes

Atomicity of work is like giving a birth to my baby. Common sense applies. The Mother Nature knows it takes about 9 months to deliver my baby, no matter how many sisters are around me, 9 months cannot get "faster" -- incompressibility of time ( as we know it, so far, in 2024-Aug ) and incompressibility of organic flow of work ( no tricks "help" here, we still enjoy being humans ). Running (almost) incompressible water down the hill can go faster, if we create more "parallel" riverbeds down the hill, to split & stream the water flows ( "DATA"-flows + processing ) all the water gets down sooner.

Last, but not least, NEVER pay more, than you receive back ( in SPEEDUP ) ... Yes, the nightmare introduced by ADD-ON COSTS. In case I can "create" 16 new "river-beds" down the hill, to run the water faster, in parallel, all the add-on costs ( of going to buy 64 excavators for bulldozing works, hiring 256 new operators for 3-shift work to build "new riverbeds" and drivers for moving material out of the new riverbeds... ) shall not take more time ( and money... ) to build "new (COMPUTING) infrastructure" than to just wait the time the water runs down the current riverbed just by itself  :o)

@Rainman always welcome :o)

Brgds also to Baron Major General Sir Nils Olav III ;o)
